# Построение векторных полей в pyqtgraph

Tags: matplotlib, vector, pyqt6, pyqtgraph

Недавно решил переписать своё приложение по построению векторных электростатических полей с *TKinter* на *PyQT6*. В предыдущей версии для отрисовки графика я использовал matplotlib и её функцию **streamplot()**. При переходе на *PyQT* решил также переписать расчётную часть, и меня привлекла библиотека *pyqtgraph*, но я не смог найти в ней подобие функции из *matplotlib*. Существует ли она, если да, то насколько отличается от использования **streamplot()**?

P.s. *Pyqtgraph* привлекла производительностью, и если у неё нет подобной функции, то какие ещё производительные библиотеки можете предложить с аналогом **streamplot()**?